# Responsive "list" in two columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a list of two types of items, let's call them green and red. In resolutions below 980 I want them stacked in one column, in resolutions above 980 I want them stacked in two columns.

This is what I got so far: http://kristofferk.se/list-test/
(Play around with your browser width to see the one/two column-thing.)

**My question**: is there an easy way to make the items stack (without the vertical space in between) using just CSS? Not interested in jQuery etc.

Thanks!

Comment: This is what I want it to look like in two columns: http://kristofferk.se/list-test/this.php

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your results through **CSS media queries**  this is the roughly idea what i am mentioning below:-

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 980px)
 {
      .class {
        background: #ccc;
      }
    }
```

read more about media queries :- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

**UPDATED**

just give **clear:right** to your **.in class**  that vertical space will remove....

```
.in {
    clear: right;
    color: green;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not my question. As you can see http://kristofferk.se/list-test/ I already got the responsive parts covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
.in {
    clear: right;
    color: green;
    float: right;
}
.in + .in {
 margin-bottom:-30px;
}
```

Comment: That only stacks the .out elements though.

Comment: Basically, it's not a margin issue at all.

Comment: If it's possible (without javascript), it probably has something to do with floats and clears and stuff.

Comment: This is what I want it to look like in two columns. http://kristofferk.se/list-test/this.php